# Unbuffer windows programs

Tags: windows, perl, console

I would like to get child output as soon as it gets printed, and not all at once when child finishes, ie.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# this is only example of buffered child output
open (my $fh, "-|", "perl", "-E", "sleep(1),say for 1..10") // die $!;

# all lines are buffered
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print $line;
}
```

On linux it can be achieved with [unbuffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer).

Comment: I find that adding `\$ = 1` to the child works ... on Linux (can't test on Windows right now).  Don't know whether it suits the purpose? It requires access to the child program.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the child, and it seems that on windows it can be done by emulating console environment https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549033/223226

Comment: That's basically what `unbuffer` does in unix too.

Comment: Using a module that sets up pty's?

Comment: Yes, something in that direction. Perhaps https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Console

Comment: It works with `Expect` (confirmed) -- again, on Linux.  Any chance to use Cygwin?

Comment: Tnx for the info but can't switch to cygwin.