# Asynchronous reading of an stdout

Tags: raku

I've wrote this simple script, it generates one output line per second (generator.sh):

```bash
for i in {0..5}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

The raku program will launch this script and will print the lines as soon as they appear:

```raku
my $proc = Proc::Async.new("sh", "generator.sh");
$proc.stdout.tap({ .print });
my $promise = $proc.start;
await $promise;
```

All works as expected: every second we see a new line. But let's rewrite generator in raku (generator.raku):

```raku
for 0..5 { .say; sleep 1 }
```

and change the first line of the program to this:

```raku
my $proc = Proc::Async.new("raku", "generator.raku");
```

Now something wrong: first we see first line of output ("0"), then a long pause, and finally we see all the remaining lines of the output.

I tried to grab output of the generators via `script` command:

```bash
script -c 'sh generator.sh' script-sh
script -c 'raku generator.raku' script-raku
```

And to analyze them in a hexadecimal editor, and it looks like they are the same: after each digit, bytes `0d` and `0a` follow.

Why is such a difference in working with seemingly identical generators? I need to understand this because I am going to launch an external program and process its output online.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why is such a difference in working with seemingly identical generators?

First, with regard to the title, the issue is not about the reading side, but rather the writing side.

Raku's I/O implementation looks at whether STDOUT is attached to a [TTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY). If it is a TTY, any output is immediately written to the output handle. However, if it's not a TTY, then it will apply buffering, which results in a significant performance improvement but at the cost of the output being chunked by the buffer size.

If you change `generator.raku` to disable output buffering:

```
$*OUT.out-buffer = False; for 0..5 { .say; sleep 1 }
```

Then the output will be seen immediately.

> I need to understand this because I am going to launch an external program and process its output online.

It'll only be an issue if the external program you launch also has such a buffering policy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer of @Jonathan Worthington. Although buffering is an issue of writing side, it is possible to cope with this on the reading side. `stdbuf`, `unbuffer`, `script` can be used on linux (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) discussion). On windows only `winpty` helps me, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531837/20425103).

So, if there are `winpty.exe`, `winpty-agent.exe`, `winpty.dll`, `msys-2.0.dll` files in working directory, this code can be used to run program without buffering:

```raku
my $proc = Proc::Async.new(<winpty.exe -Xallow-non-tty -Xplain raku generator.raku>);
```