Reading stdout of non-python subprocess continuously
I have an executable that I need to run which outputs messages to the stdout while running, however when using subprocess, it seems to wait for the script to finish completely before sending the messages.
Note: Using Windows 10
The executable that I will need to run is not a Python process, so it can not be fixed by adding sys.stdout.flush(), python -u ... etc.
main.py
import subprocess

popen = subprocess.Popen(["my_process"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in popen.stdout: 
    print(line)

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? I am planning to implement this in a PyQt gui using QProcess, though the problem is also present in that implementation.

Why you cant use the 2 fixes you mentioned ? Additionally you could set -u using env variable

I guess the actual executable in the subprocess isn't a Python script? Have you checked (by directly calling the executable in the console) if it really outputs during (and not after) execution?

Yes the reason I can't use -u is because its not a python file but an executable. When I run the executable through cmd it does output information continuously.
I did however notice that when I replace the print in the loop with "print(f"{i}" * 10000)", it does output it directly, so it appears to be a buffer problem? Though when I change the buffer of Popen to 0 it still doesn't work.

@bgen: Is the executable a Python application ?

No, that was just to demonstrate the same effect. Sorry if that wasn't clear. The application I actually have to run is a compiled executable which I have no way to edit.

@bgen: Does the executable write to stdout while running in the console ?

@MauriceMeyer Yes

check the documentation for Popen, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen. , in particular :  bufsize will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the open() function when creating the stdin/stdout/stderr pipe file objects:
0 means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short)
1 means line buffered (only usable if text=True or universal_newlines=True)
any other positive value means use a buffer of approximately that size
negative bufsize (the default) means the system default of io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE will be used.

I tried your code with sys.stdout.flush() under Linux and it works just fine. I am sorry I don't have any Windows machine to try it, but I guess it is a Windows-specific issue. If you can, try to run your code under Windows Subsystem for Linux, or Cygwin to see if you get a different outcome.

You could run the executable through the unbuffer command. This redirects stdout through a pty, so it will not buffer its output.

@HaiVu Yes, that's the problem. If you use the flush it works, but the exe i need to run doesn't use it and I am unable to edit it.

@Barmar How? Is that linux only? Do you have any more information to get me going?

@ticktalk Yes I already mentioned in a previous comment that I tried setting the buffer to 0 and that It did not solve the problem for my example.

Sorry, yes, unbuffer is a Linux command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516258/what-is-the-equivalent-of-unbuffer-program-on-windows

if you have WSL ... believe it has the stdbuf utility (at least thats what ubuntu alleges), it may also have the unbuffer utility mentioned (no experience of using that btw)
bgen.py
import subprocess
import sys
import datetime

cmd = [ "/home/tester/someprocess" ]

if 'stdbuf' in sys.argv:
    cmd = [ "/usr/bin/stdbuf", "-o0", "/home/tester/someprocess" ]

print(f'{datetime.datetime.now()} :: running: {cmd}' )

popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in popen.stdout: 
    print(f'{datetime.datetime.now()} :: got:{line.rstrip()}')

someprocess.c
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for( int iter=0; iter <= 5; iter++ ){
        printf( "iteration %d\n", iter );
        sleep(1);
    }
}

# buffered 
python bgen.py
2024-08-19 16:18:44.366847 :: running: ['/home/tester/someprocess']
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368800 :: got:iteration 0
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368871 :: got:iteration 1
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368908 :: got:iteration 2
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368937 :: got:iteration 3
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368966 :: got:iteration 4
2024-08-19 16:18:50.368994 :: got:iteration 5

# unbuffered
python bgen.py stdbuf
2024-08-19 16:18:58.908986 :: running: ['/usr/bin/stdbuf', '-o0', '/home/tester/someprocess']
2024-08-19 16:18:58.910353 :: got:iteration 0
2024-08-19 16:18:59.910556 :: got:iteration 1
2024-08-19 16:19:00.910656 :: got:iteration 2
2024-08-19 16:19:01.910810 :: got:iteration 3
2024-08-19 16:19:02.910920 :: got:iteration 4
2024-08-19 16:19:03.911044 :: got:iteration 5

hope this helps ...

I should have specified but i'm looking to get this working on windows.

@bgen, np, i am not a windows user, but believe the WSL is available for Windows 10  - if still unsuitable just ignore my post.
